# React clone an object from parent props keeps getting updated on re-render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props

Not sure what the fix is for this. We get an array of objects from our API and use this to create data in the view. At the same time in a child component (filters) I want to map over one of the fields in the data to create my filter categories. The filter will call new data from the API with a param, and that data is returned and updates the props (I think this is the issue as this reredners the child component using the filtered data to set the categories again).

I thought putting the array inside useEffect would stop it being updated.

Here is the current tsx in my Filter Component:

```
const ExclusiveOffersFilters = (props: ExclusiveOffersFiltersProps): JSX.Element => {
  const newFilters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.options)); // copy the object from props
  let filterOffers;

  useEffect(() => {
    filterOffers = newFilters.map((item: any) => {
      return { value: item.offerType, display: item.offerType };
    });
    console.log('filterOffers: ', filterOffers); // succesfully logs the filtered items. 
  }, []);

  return (
    <tr>
      <th>
        <Filter
          options={filterOffers} // here filterOffers is undefined
          alignRight={props.alignRight}
          handleClick={props.handleFilterChange}
          multiSelect={props.multiSelect}
          selectedItems={props.selectedItems}
        />
      </th>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

I also tried const `newFilters = [...props.options];` and `newFilters = props.options.slice(0)` but it is the same issue (the wisdom seemed to be to use JSON parse/stringify).

In my parent component I am calling the child like so:

`<ExclusiveOffersFilters handleFilterChange={props.handleFilterChange} options={props.options} />`

If I remove the `useEffect` function and just update the filters it will work, however after selecting one filter the app updates the api call, only receives filtered data back and therefore only one category is set in the filters. Which I need to prevent.

I need a way to get the original categories and freeze them from being updated.

**EDIT**

Here is our sample data:

```
const data = [
  {
    offerId: 1,
    partnerName: "Another offer 4",
    imageUrl:
      "https://www.auctsjpg-w263-h98-99382466814e33da0cfa3d5d2afd921c.jpg",
    description:
      "Save up to 10% on something. <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>",
    header: "Save up to 10%",
    enabled: true,
    deleted: false,
    offerType: "Motoring"
  },
  {
    offerId: 0,
    partnerName: "Amazing offer 4",
    imageUrl: "https://www.cGen",
    description:
      "Save up to 20% off* your business insurance thanks to our partnership with<BR/> Churchill Expert. Simply visit the Churchill Expert web page and choose the<BR/> insurance product to suit your business.<BR/>     Churchill Expert will automatically apply the discount to your premium for the<BR/>duration of your policy.     <BR/><BR/>*Minimum premiums apply. Discount applies to NIG policies arranged by Churchill Expert <BR/>and underwritten by U K Insurance Limited.<BR/> Professional Indemnity excluded.",
    header: "Save up to 20% off",
    enabled: true,
    deleted: false,
    offerType: "Insurance"
  },
  {
    offerId: 190,
    partnerName: "Amazing offer 4",
    imageUrl: "https://www.ch.Code=ExpertGen",
    description:
      "Save up to 20% off* your business insurance thanks to our partnership with<BR/> Churchill Expert. Simply visit the Churchill Expert web page and choose the<BR/> insurance product to suit your business.<BR/>     Churchill Expert will automatically apply the discount to your premium for the<BR/>duration of your policy.     <BR/><BR/>*Minimum premiums apply. Discount applies to NIG policies arranged by Churchill Expert <BR/>and underwritten by U K Insurance Limited.<BR/> Professional Indemnity excluded.",
    header: "Save up to 20% off",
    enabled: true,
    deleted: true,
    offerType: "Insurance"
  }
];

export default data;
```

If we filter on offerType = Motoring then we call our api again with Motoring as our filter this will only return 1 record from the above data, but now our filter gets updated and only shows 1 filter category of Motoring.

See attached examples from the app.

[image]
[image]

I have dumped most of the files here: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sinoussi-l2iwh?file=/data.js:0-2061 with sample data. I don't know how helpful this is, it is hard to make a working example when there are so many dependencies.

The parent index.tsx handles all of the ajax api calls and passes down data into the props. The ExclusiveOffersFilters.tsx receives this and gets updated, which is the part I want to stop. As @Adam points out in the comments we are trying to fix this, but I think actually the parent is fine, it is the child that is the issue.

We do want to apply this logic elsewhere in the app, so performance would be good. I am wondering if I just need to not use props.options and use a different prop for this?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to fix an issue in your child component by applying a hack in your parent component (two wrongs don't make a right). Post the code for the child component and I have a feeling it'll be obvious immediately what the problem is.

Comment: @Adam I have updated my question, with a link to most of the files, sample data and screenshots of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need. If you run into performance issues, use `useMemo`. If you don't run into performance issues, don't do anything

```
const ExclusiveOffersFilters = (props: ExclusiveOffersFiltersProps): JSX.Element => {

  const filters = props.options.map((item) => ({
    value: item.offerType, 
    display: item.offerType
  }));

  return (
    <tr>
      <th>
        <Filter
          options={filters}
          alignRight={props.alignRight}
          handleClick={props.handleFilterChange}
          multiSelect={props.multiSelect}
          selectedItems={props.selectedItems}
        />
      </th>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

Example with `useMemo`

```
 const filters = useMemo(() => props.options.map(....),[props.options]);
```

I cannot stress enough to stay away from `useMemo` unless you're absolutely sure you need it.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try but I suspect the props.options will get updated on the rerender.

Comment: @lharby It will, but I've re-read your question and two things - first, the whole JSON.parse JSON.stringify stuff is nonsense, and second, you're trying to fix a bug in your lower component by adding a hack to this component. Post the code for the lower component that you say keeps updating and fix the bug where it actually is, instead of hacking this component.

Comment: OK, I will pick this up tomorrow and update, thank you so much for your input

Comment: @lharby - your codepen doesn't work right now, but I can almost guarantee the problem is related to your use of `splice` and `push` in `Filter.tsx`. When it comes to react, don't mutate anything, state, props, anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. `useEffect` performs async so the `filterOffers` can be undefined on the moment of the render.
2. If you want to create a value based on some other value and want to optimize it use `useMemo` hook.
3. If you want to store a value between re-renders of a component use `useRef` hook.

   ```
   const newFilters = useRef(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.options))); // copy the object from props
   const filterOffers = useMemo(() => {
        filterOffers = newFilters.current.map((item: any) => {
            return { value: item.offerType, display: item.offerType };
        });
        console.log('filterOffers: ', filterOffers); // succesfully logs the filtered items. 
   }, [newFilters]);
   ```

Comment: Why are you using `useRef`? Are are you adding `newFilters` as a dependency to `useMemo`? `newFilters` is a ref and will never change.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the question, but the idea was to keep them saved between re-renders.

Comment: As far as I understood the OP wants to save the original filters between re-renders that is why I am using `useRef`

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, I cannot quite seem to get it to work. But you have made filterOffers a const and then you are calling it again inside the useMemo function. 
I have updated my question with a link to resources, sample data and screenshots. I think the function should be `const filterOffers = useMemo(() => {
     return filterOffers = newFilters.current.map((item: any) => {
         return { value: item.offerType, display: item.offerType };
     });
     console.log('filterOffers: ', filterOffers); // succesfully logs the filtered items. 
}, [newFilters]);`

Comment: Sorry that formatting is horrible. It seems to be the same issue I was having, the map appears to work, but outside of the function filterOffers is an empty array.

Comment: @lharby sorry, but by virtue of this answer putting `newFilters` in the dependency array of `useMemo`, it clearly demonstrates the incoherence of this answer. It won't help you.